How do you make sure a random integer is divisible by another random number in a math game
I am making a game in Python where you answer math questions. I have added 3 operations: addition, subtraction and multiplication. They have 5 modes, each harder than the other.
Now I want to add division. But the random numbers for the easy, normal and hard modes are not always divisible. How do I make them divisible?
I used the % operator but I couldn't figure out how to use it in a random number generator.
My code:
# 'd' for division
elif response == "d":
    # this function asks the user for the mode
    mode_opt = input(ask_mode_opt)
    if mode_opt == 'E'.lower():
        no2 = random.randint(1, 10)
        math_func(guesses=10, no1=random.randint(1, 10), no2=no2, data_type=int, operator=3, str_op='÷', full_op_text='e')
        replay_or_exit()
    elif mode_opt == 'N'.lower():
        no2=random.randint(2, 20)
        math_func(guesses=5, no1=random.randint(2, no2), no2=no2, data_type=int, operator=3, str_op='÷', full_op_text='n')
        replay_or_exit()
    elif mode_opt == 'H'.lower():
        no2=random.randint(2, 50)
        math_func(guesses=4, no1=random.randint(2, no2), no2=no2, data_type=int, operator=3, str_op='÷', full_op_text='h')
        replay_or_exit()
    elif mode_opt == 'I'.lower():
        math_func(guesses=4, no1=random.randint(2, 100), no2=random.randint(2, 100), data_type=int, operator=3, str_op='÷', full_op_text='i')
        replay_or_exit()
    elif mode_opt == 'C'.lower():
        math_func(guesses=5, no1=round(random.uniform(2, 100), 2), no2=round(random.uniform(2, 100), 2), data_type=float, operator=3, str_op='÷', full_op_text='c')
        replay_or_exit()


Why do you write 'E'.lower() instead of just 'e'? Maybe you meant if mode_opt.upper() == 'E':?

It might help to make a [mre]. I don't think we need to see all the modes; just one would do without input(ask_mode_opt); but on the flip side, it might help to see how the code goes from there. Should be doable in about 10 lines of code. No need for functions for a basic example.

@teapot418 Please don't post answers in the comments; post an answer instead :)

@jasonharper Please don't post answers in the comments; post an answer instead :)

replay_or_exit() also doesn't seem relevant to the problem, so please remove it from the example. But BTW, it's better practice to use iteration than recursion. Check out Rabbid76's answer here and Volatility's answer here.

I'd recommend to, instead of generating two random numbers until they're divisible, generate two numbers a and b and multiply them, so that the result c will always be divisible by a and b (c = a * b). You can then set no1 and no2 (which are, if I understood correctly, the numbers the player should divide) to e.g. c and a, and expect the result to be b.

Thank you so much
